# Contains value xslt2

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How is it possible to check if an array of for example Strings contains a String?

```
<xsl:if test="inArray('a', $array)"></xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If by array you mean sequence, just use `=`...

```
    <xsl:variable name="array" select="('a','b','c')"/>
    <xsl:if test="$array='a'"></xsl:if>
```

You can also test multiple values in an array/sequence (this example will evaluate true if `a` or `c` exists in the sequence):

```
    <xsl:if test="$array=('a','c')"></xsl:if>
```

Comment: haha, now I feel bad for not thinking of this in my answer...it probably was just too obvious :) ...you get my upvote